# is it possible to undo convertion from raid5 to raid6?

Tags: mdadm

I converted my 3-disk RAID5 to RAID6 with :

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md1 --level=6 --layout=preserve --force
```

The change was immediate, (no rebuilding - there was no extra device, it was still 3 drives), but now naturally the array will not assemble without --run because it wants 4 drives.

So now I want to turn it back to RAID5.

I tried

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md1 --level=5
```

and mdadm replies:

```
mdadm: failed to set raid disks
```

Is there a way to undo my mistake?
Thanks.

---

Additional info:
I think that I remember my previous configuration was with 64K chunk size, I am not absolutely sure.
I have tried to add an old (unreliable) disk to the array but after hours of syncing and booting various versions of ubuntu I have removed it again and I may have rearranged the layout of the disks on the controller, again I am not sure in what way.

then it became like this:

```
/dev/md1:
        Version : 01.02
  Creation Time : Mon Jul 23 16:24:43 2012
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 5782407168 (5514.53 GiB 5921.18 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5782407168 (5514.53 GiB 5921.18 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Fri Apr 10 15:00:05 2015
          State : active, degraded
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : :New RAID Array
           UUID : 89e8e508:dc49a4d7:8ccdb79f:7d5b4d5d
         Events : 102194

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       4       8       18        0      active sync   /dev/sdb2
       5       8       34        1      active sync   /dev/sdc2
       2       0        0        2      removed
       6       8        2        3      active sync   /dev/sda2
```

how is it that the chunk size is now 512K when the original was 64K? is it because of the sync? 
can I turn the array back to raid5 with

```
mdadm --create -l 5 -n 3 --assume-clean /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sda2
```

or perhaps without --assume-clean and replacing /dev/sda2 with missing, and add it back later if that works?
And if I do should I use 64K or 512K chunk size?